# Multiple Split views in one App

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad

I am building an iPad app and wish to have the user open to a main menu screen (UIView). The view will contain several buttons that each, in turn, will load a different split view controller. Which each will have a table view to load different nibs.

I have the nibs and table views but I don't know to code for different split views.

Can I do this?

Thanks for your help

Dave

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your looking for something like this: [MultipleDetailViews](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009775)